# Retrieve GSM network information Android?

Tags: android

I want gsm network information like BCCH, BSIC etc in my android application. How can i retrieve this using android SDK?

Answer (score 1):

```
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

The telephonyManager is your friend. ;)

Comment: BCCH and BSIC are low level network information and they aren't available in TelephonyManager. So unfortunately telephonyManager isn't my friend here. :(

Comment: Did you find a way to retrieve bcch and bsic @Anjesh ?